# Find the tangent line at pont $q=(a,b)$ of the following curves.

Tags: vector-analysis, parametric

I need help with this problem:

> Find, where appropriate the equation of the tangent line to $C$ at the point $q=(a,b)$ on $C$. Indicate points on $C$ where no tangent line exists.

1. the $y$-axis, $x=0$.
2. the parabola $y+1=(x-2)^2$.
3. the circle $(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2=4$

For 1. I used the parametrization $f(t)=(0,t)$ and the derivative at $a$ is $f'(a)=(0,1)$. For 2. I used the parametrization $f(t)=(t+2,t^2-1)$ and 
$f'(a)=(1, 2t)$ and for 3. I used $f(t)=(2\cos t+1, 2\sin t+2)$ and $f'(a)=(-2\sin t, 2\cos t)$.

How do I find the equation of the tangent line at q?

Comment: How do you usually find the slope of the tangent? You use $dy/dx.$ How do you determine $dy/dx$ in a parametric situation? The derivatives $dy/dt$ and $dx/dt$ should play a role.

Comment: So I need to calculate $dy/dt$ and $dx/dt$ for $t=a$?

Comment: There should be a value of the parameter $t$ for which $x(t)=a$ and $y(t)=b.$ Evaluate at this value of $t.$

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the tangent line is $y-y_0=y'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ or $x-x_0=x'(y_0)(y-y_0)$.

**1**

$$x=0\implies x'=0.$$ Thus we have that the tangent line at $(0,y_0)$ is $x=0$.

**2**

$$y=(x-2)^2 -1\implies y'=2x-4.$$ Thus, the tangent line at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $$y-y_0=(2x_0-4)(x-x_0)$$ where $y_0=(x_0-2)^2 -1.$

**3**

$$(x-1)^2 +(y-2)^2=1 \implies x-1+(y-2)y'=0, (x-1)x'+y-2=0.$$

So, if $y\ne 2$ then $y'=-\frac{x-1}{y-2}$ and if $x\ne 1$ then $x'=-frac{y-2}{x-1}.$

Comment: I don't understand what you did. Why $y=0$?

Comment: I have misread the question. I thought it was $y=0.$ Anyway, I have modified the answer.

Comment: I still don't understad, sorry. For (2) I used $x=t+2/4$ and $y=t^2-1$. Then I used $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$ and I ended p=up with $2t$. For the first one I don't know what to do and for (3) I did the same with $x=2\cos t +1$ and $y=2\sin t +2$ and I ended up with $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2\sin t}{2\cos t}$. What do I do next?